# Kill jquery setTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
loading = setTimeout(function(){$("#myDiv").html('3');},1500)
loading = setTimeout(function(){$("#myDiv").html('2');},2500)
loading = setTimeout(function(){$("#myDiv").html('1');},3500)
loading = setTimeout(function(){$("#myDiv").html('Go!');},4500)
```

I have that code for example which counts down until something starts. But if a user clicks a button called "Stop" I want the countdown to stop. I am aware of the clearTimeout and I have used clearTimeout(loading) but this does not work. I believe it's because loading is redefined a second later.

Thanks

Comment: what about using setInterval?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

clearTimout wasn't working because you are reusing 'loading' variable. Try this:

```
loading1 = setTimeout(function(){$("#myDiv").html('3');},1500);
loading2 = setTimeout(function(){$("#myDiv").html('2');},2500);
loading3 = setTimeout(function(){$("#myDiv").html('1');},3500);
loading4 = setTimeout(function(){$("#myDiv").html('Go!');},4500);


$("#stop").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    clearTimeout(loading1);
    clearTimeout(loading2);
    clearTimeout(loading3);
    clearTimeout(loading4);
});
```

Comment: For more than just a few timeouts, however, a loop would be preferable - or a chained timeout.

Answer (score 2):

With [setInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp), you will be able to actually pause the timer (which is impossible with [setTimeout](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)):

```
var previousTime = Date.now();
var elapsed = 0;
var stop = false;
var step = 3;

var timer = setInterval(function(){countdown()},100);

var countdown = function() {
   if (!stop) {
       elapsed += Date.now() - previousTime;
    }
    previousTime = Date.now();

    if (elapsed >= 1500 && step == 3) {
        $("#myDiv").html('3');
        step--;
    }
    else if (elapsed >= 2500 && step == 2) {
        $("#myDiv").html('2');
        step--;
    }
    else if (elapsed >= 3500 && step == 1) {
        $("#myDiv").html('1');
        step--;
    }
    else if (elapsed >= 4500 && step == 0) {
        $("#myDiv").html('Go!');
        step = 1000;
        clearInterval(timer);
    }
}

$("#stop").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    stop = true;
});
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p2u5j/)

Comment: That's another way to do it.

Comment: Give a try on the jsfiddle I just added, you will see it's slightly different if you restart the countdown (just click again on stop to do it)

Comment: Oh... I see. So you effectively pause the timer. I tried to do that but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Clicking **stop** should set a boolean, which you can check for in each `setTimout` function before changing the HTML.

```
var loading = [],
    mydiv = document.getElementById("myDiv"),
    stopped = false;

function countdown(number){
    if(!stopped){
        mydiv.innerHTML = number;
    }
}

loading[0] = setTimeout(function(){countdown("3")},1500);
loading[1] = setTimeout(function(){countdown("2")},2500);
loading[2] = setTimeout(function(){countdown("1")},3500);
loading[3] = setTimeout(function(){countdown("0")},4500);

$("#stop").on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    stopped = true;
});
```

**Find the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HTRTL/1/) here.**